# DBCC SHRINKFILE failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc

I'm trying to shrink a database on a test system but the file won't get any smaller. The size of the mdf file is 47 GB and unused space is 38 GB. A lot of data was removed from the database hence the large amount of unused space.

The following error appears:
Start dbcc shrinkfile ( Olympus_dat, 46912 ) at 2015-07-23 15:27:19.300
DBCC SHRINKFILE: Page 1:6017543 could not be moved because it has not been formatted.

How can I fix this error?

SQL Server 2012 x64

Additional information.
The following queries return an error:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
GO

DBCC page('Olympus', 1, 6017543, 1)
Go

DBCC TRACEOFF(3604)
GO
```

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

PAGE: (14440:908631589)

BUFFER:

BUF @0x0000000009682040

bpage = 0x00000002B46B8000          bhash = 0x0000000000000000          bpageno = (1:6017543)
bdbid = 6                           breferences = 1                     bcputicks = 0
bsampleCount = 0                    bUse1 = 23548                       bstat = 0x809
blog = 0x5adb215a                   bnext = 0x0000000000000000

PAGE HEADER:

Page @0x00000002B46B8000

m_pageId = (14440:908631589)        m_headerVersion = 252               m_type = 226
m_typeFlagBits = 0xf9               m_level = 216                       m_flagBits = 0xd676
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = -1238914908                                m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 23941
Metadata: AllocUnitId = 6738992698879115264                              Metadata: PartitionId = 0
Metadata: IndexId = -1              Metadata: ObjectId = 0              m_prevPage = (35510:854211095)
m_nextPage = (61606:1041616947)     pminlen = 43990                     m_slotCnt = 27900
m_freeCnt = 40464                   m_freeData = 34288                  m_reservedCnt = 12643
m_lsn = (-257029635:1920476993:30788)                                    m_xactReserved = 11969
m_xdesId = (25449:1820050307)       m_ghostRecCnt = 61532               m_tornBits = -213551362
DB Frag ID = 1

Allocation Status

GAM (1:5623552) = ALLOCATED         SGAM (1:5623553) = ALLOCATED
PFS (1:6017472) = 0x40 ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL                            DIFF (1:5623558) = NOT CHANGED
ML (1:5623559) = NOT MIN_LOGGED

CompressionInfo @0x00000000309682B0

CompressionInfo Raw Bytes

CompressionInfo size (in bytes) = 0 PageModCount = 50289                CI Header Flags =

DATA:

Slot 0, Offset 0x4ad2, Length 1, DumpStyle BYTE

Record Type = (COMPRESSED) EMPTY_GHOST_RECORD                            Record size = 1

CD Array

Record Memory Dump

000000003096EAD2:   05                                            .
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: Anybody know the answer to this question?

Comment: This is corruption. Run DBCC CHECKDB.

Comment: I've done this a couple of times but no errors are found anymore. There were errors before but if fixed those errors by executing `DBCC CHECKDB('Olympus',REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)`. Now I'm left with above problem. The database works as expected, I just can't shrink it.

Comment: That sounds like a CHECKDB bug in that it does not repair all problems. Report this to Microsoft and get this fixed for everyone.

Comment: What's the best way to report this problem? Via the MSDN forum?

Comment: MS Connect. Upload the corrupt DB (before repairs) privately. Private uploads are a feature of Connect. It's important to give them a repro.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the steps given in the answer at the bottom of the page,

https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/19676/dbcc-shrinkfile-error.html

Comment: Hi Jigar, I've tried these steps but the select returned NULL.

Comment: Is it possible to restart the SQL server services?

Comment: Yes it's a test system so I can do everything :-)

Comment: link's broken...